# where pdf from EXM attachment stored?

Tags: exm

do you know where PDF is stored when we upload it as email attachment from Email Experience Manager? I am using exm 3.1
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXM stores all attachments in /sitecore/media library/Email Campaign/Attachments